# how to find begin date of the history logs present in Ibm as400 device? - history log collection

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am trying to collect *history logs* from ibm as400 device using `DSPLOG PERIOD((*AVAIL *BEGIN) (*AVAIL *END)) OUTPUT(*PRTWRAP)` command.

But print(prtwrap) cannot exceed a limit of 999999, hence i cannot fetch the entire logs from *BEGIN to *END all together(replying nomax isn't an option as i am running these commands in remote command in my java program).

So how to find the begin date of the history logs present in the device so that i can start using the same command in a loop sequentially increasing the date range and not the entire date range all together.

How to find the start date of the history logs present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can use HISTORY_LOG_INFO()

```
select * from table(
    HISTORY_LOG_INFO(
        START_TIME => current date - 6 days,
        END_TIME => current date - 5 days
    )
) as log
```

[more info](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzajq/rzajqudfhistoryloginfo.htm)

Comment: while executing this query i get a issue as RUNSQLSTMT OR RUNSQL failed

Comment: not on my machine, what is the error description ? i think the OS has to be at v7.2 minimum

Comment: So your query will give me a output log with start_date from 6 days before today?

Comment: Yes, and end 24 hours later

Comment: but is it possible to get to get the exact start date of the history log,
i need the beginning date of history logs.

Comment: with `select * from table(HISTORY_LOG_INFO()) as log` you will have all logs

Comment: and `select min(MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP) as first_message from table(HISTORY_LOG_INFO()) as log` will give you the first date in the history

Comment: Does HISTORY_LOG_INFO() table contain BRMS logs? or is it stored in a different table?

Answer (score 0):

A quick usage of Google [reveals](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rbam6/systl.htm):

> The history log (QHST) consists of a message queue and a physical file known as a log version.

So you can either access the physical file directly (and hope, the format will not change) or use the API calls also mentioned in that article.